# setting value to unknown salary

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite3 online compiling. I wanted to create a table where one of the employee has a value of unknown salary.

Here is my sqlite3 code.

where John Doe works at Burger Steak but his salary is unknown.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
/* Create a table called Works */
CREATE TABLE Works(employee_name text, company_name text, salary varchar);
/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO Works VALUES('John Smith', 'Starbucks Coffee', '2000 USD');
INSERT INTO Works VALUES('Peter Cruz', 'Mc Donalds', '3000 USD');
INSERT INTO Works VALUES('John Doe', 'Burger Steak', '');
COMMIT;
```

The output is

```
John Smith|Starbucks Coffee|2000 USD
Peter Cruz|Mc Donalds|3000 USD
John Doe|Burger Steak|
```

Am I doing this right? Is the unknown salary should be leave blank? what about NULL values, how I could apply it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using NULL for unknown or inapplicable values. To do so, you would have something like:

```
INSERT INTO Works (
    employee_name,
    company_name,
    salary
) VALUES (
    'John Doe',
    'Burger Steak',
    NULL
);
```

You should probably also be using a numeric field for numeric values (like salary) if you ever envisage performing calculations with them.

Comment: please teach me how to use NULL in this particular case, im so sorry i am just new in sqlite

Comment: thank you so much i think that is the statement im searching for. I've been trying also `INSERT INTO Works (
    employee_name,
    company_name,
    salary
) VALUES (
    'John Doe',
    'Burger Steak',
    'NULL'
);` i was wrong in putting qoute. thank you so much for the enlightenment.